# error message on azure : SQLSTATE[HY000] [3159] Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON

Tags: php, sql, azure, mysql-workbench

i'm trying to run my project on azure. I added a mysql server and web app project, everything seems to be works but i have this message when i run my web app :

`"SQLSTATE[HY000] [3159] Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.`"

i found this solution

```
"ALTER USER '<user>'@'<host/Ip-address>' REQUIRE <tls_option>; [ tls_option: { SSL | X509 | CIPHER 'cipher' | ISSUER 'issuer' | SUBJECT 'subject' } ]"
```

but i don't understand where can i use it. i can replace the user and host/ip-address, but i don't understand how can i replace the tls_option? also, can i use this query on mysql workbench? thank you !

Comment: are you connecting to the db by making a connection string?

Answer (score 0):

The error you pasted in your question is self-explanatory; you are trying to connect a client which *don't use* encryption with a server that *requires* it.

The *right* solution is to modify the client configuration so that secure connection is used. Maybe you miss the `openssl` package on a client, or the MySQL library was built without openssl support?

By the way; what you pasted as a "possible solution" isn't one - it allows you to edit server's behavior for a user about *his own* encryption requirements, but if encryption is mandated *server-wide*, it will always take precedence.